# react router 4 - Nested Switch not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, router

App.js

```
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" name="Layout" component={Layout} />
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />
        <Route component={NoMatch}/>
    </Switch>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

Layout.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/components/a" component={ComponentA} />
    <Route path="/components/b" component={ComponentB} />
</Switch>
```

- Problems:

  - **problem#1** navigate to '/dashboard/components/a' or '/dashboard/components/b' not display component a or b as expected
  - **problem#2** navigate to wrong path always redirect to '/dashboard' not display NoMatch component

UPDATE:
changing Redirect to

    `<Route exact path='/' render={() => <Redirect to='/dashboard' />} />`

can fix the **problem #2** but **problem #1** remains

Comment: try using `<Redirect from='/' to="/components/a" />` after `<Route path="/components/a" component={ComponentA} />`

Comment: try putting `exact` on your routes?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your `Route` path to have a `/dashboard` param as well when you are tyring to navigate to `/dashboard/componenets/a` or `/dashboard/componenets/b`

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/dashboard/components/a" component={ComponentA} />
    <Route path="/dashboard/components/b" component={ComponentB} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: that's not working. The problem may be due to `exact` in `<Route exact path='/' render={() => <Redirect to='/dashboard' />} />`
but if I remove `exact`, it displays blank page???

Comment: What if you simply use <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" /> with the above configuration